# How to use VBA Code to print a specific page to pdf depending on the value of a cell

Tags: excel

I am not very advanced with `Excel` or `VBA` but have managed to work a few things out over time.

I currently have an Excel Spreadsheet with a command button which sends the print area to PDF.  It is fairly simple with just 2 pages to print.

I would like the command button to print either just page 1, just page 2, or pages 1 & 2 depending on the value of a cell.

The code I am currently using to print all of the print area to PDF is:

```
Sub PrinttoPDF()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=Range("J2").Value & "_" & Range("J4").Value & "_" & "Budget Quotation" & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Please can someone advice how to amend my code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method has `From` and `To` parameters.

Depending on whether the value of A1 on sheet 2 is 1, 2 or anything else it will print page 1, 2 or both.

I put it on a different sheet in case it messes up your printing. Adjust to suit.

And best to use the sheet name rather than `activesheet`.

```
Sub PrinttoPDF()

Dim f As Long, t As Long    
Select Case Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
    Case 1: t = 1: f = 1 'page 1
    Case 2: t = 2: f = 2 'page 2
    Case else: f = 1: t = 2 'pages 1-2
End Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=Range("J2").Value & "_" & Range("J4").Value & "_" & "Budget Quotation" & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    from:=f, _
    to:=t, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```